# How to automatically open a post in new tab when user clicks on the post?

Tags: javascript, html, blogspot

When a user come to my site and on main page when user clicks on any post on  post title that post should open in new tab. Its Google Blogger related.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: To open a link in a new tab/window (the browser controls which, you don't) you would add a `target` to the link.  For example: `<a href="somepage.html" target="_blank">link</a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

your anchor tag or link should be looks like below with `target="_blank"`:

```
<a href="Post.html" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post title will be in an anchor tag, only you must include `target` attribute and assign `_blank` as the value for that as shown below so that after clicking that it will automatically opens in a new tab.

```
<a href="http://something.com" target="_blank">Post Title</a>
```